# icarus verilog on windows7

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I used to work with iverilog on win-xp. But ever since I moved to win7, it does not work. And I am not even using GTK, I just want a plain simulation to run. I have used different versions of iverilog (0.9.4 to 0.9.6), same results.

When I compile a simple verilog (e.g. "iverilog xx.v") I get an a.out. But when I try to run the a.out (after doing "chmod +rx" on it, using cygwin), I only get the cryptic message: "no permissions".

Have any of you faced the same problem, and if so, what is the solution?

Comment: With chmod you are changing permissions. You probably first need admin rights to change them in Windows 7.

Comment: its not a question of me not having admin rights, chmod works. When I run a.exe in windows-cmd, I get a more detailed message: "The program or feature ...\a.exe cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit version of Windows." So this looks like iverilog generates executable only for 32 bit. Is there a command line option by which it can be asked to generate a 64bit executable? Or, is there a way I can run a 32bit executable on a 64bit windows machine?